# Obtain local IP address on receiving UDP

Tags: go

I would like to obtain local IP address on receiving UDP packets.

```
packetConn, _ := net.ListenPacket("udp", ":12345")
n, remoteAddr, _ := packetConn.ReadFrom(buf)
```

My server has secondary IP addresses and I would like to know to which address each client sends UDP packets.
`packetConn.ReadFrom` can get remote IP address, but I would like to get the local IP address of the UDP.

I tried `packetConn.LocalAddr()`, but this returns only local port number like `:12345`.

How can I get local IP address of UDP packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocalAddr` effectively returns the `address` value passed to [`ListenPacket`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenConfig.ListenPacket). If this is not specific enough for you, you'll need to create multiple listeners, one for each IP address on your server.